# Universal analytics goal tracking

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have set up goal to URL destination: '/pageview.html'. 
If I execute below URL on my universal analytic page views will increase by 1 (which is correct). Also my goal will increase by 1 (which is also correct).

Link 1 example

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX-4&cid=987987987&t=pageview&sr=-&sd=-&ul=-&je=0&fl=-&dt=%2Fphonecallleads.html&dh=www.wednesday.co.uk&dr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wednesday.co.uk%2Fbla%3Fhehe%3Dvisitor&dp=/phonecallleads.html&z=321321321
```

How ever if I execute the same link again but with different number in 'z' parameter to prevent caching on my analytic page views will increase by 1 (which is correct) **but my goal will not increase... Why is my goal not increasing ?**

Link example 2 witch different 'z' parameter

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX-4&cid=987987987&t=pageview&sr=-&sd=-&ul=-&je=0&fl=-&dt=%2Fphonecallleads.html&dh=www.wednesday.co.uk&dr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wednesday.co.uk%2Fbla%3Fhehe%3Dvisitor&dp=/phonecallleads.html&z=654654654
```

Comment: Probably because goals are counted only once per session ? In any case this is a question for the Webmasters site, not for the (code-related) stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know this is not the right place to ask this question but I really need a fix for this.
I have changed session timeout to 2 minutes, resubmitted the request and page view came through but goal still hasn't... 
Any ideas?

Comment: I concur with @eike's comment on both points. Check real-time to see conversions immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Eike Pierstorff. 
The issue was that UA counts goals only once per session.
To resolve that issue I have added an extra parameter to the URL - Session control which starts new session once request is submitted.
&sc=start